Identify this early 2000's mad max/post-apocalyptic-like tv show
So I can remember a few things about this show, I wonder if anyone can help me figure out the name.
I'm pretty sure it was in the early 2000's and that it was on a german tv channel (Super RTL to be precise) but I'm also sure that it was no german production, so it should be known in other countries.
Anyway, a few points I do remember about the story:

The main characters (real actors, nothing animated) were very young, I guess about 15-17 at max.
They lived in some kind of really small commune (like a wandering circus, definetly nothing big) and in a desert like environment, pretty sure it was no city
There was time travel involved, I'm sure it was to the future. But i can't really remember how it was done, either through a device or through a time rift-like-thing, I don't really remember. 
The future they went to was post-apocalyptic/mad max like, there were gangs driving around in trucks and other cars and they looked like cars in mad max, steel plates on their sides and what not, I guess you know what i mean. The area was always pretty desert-like.
The gang leader was very young himself, about 20 at max and he had very short hair, almost bald I'd say.
I think that there was a love couple between a girl from 'our' time and a boy from the future time.
The gang leader used to hunt those from the past and they always were scared but in the end they always got away (of course) and got safely back in their time.
I remember this one episode where the gang leader followed the main characters back in their time, but they did not notice him. I'm not really sure but I think he kidnapped a family member of one of our main characters so he could finally catch them.

That's pretty much everything I remember from this show. I'm really sorry it's that vague but nothing more will come to my mind. I really hope that someone out there can help me.

Could be Thunderstone 1999

A comet hit the Earth, destroying all. The world is frozen, but some humans managed to survive. Noah lives in an underground community. While improving the Holodeck, Noah accidentally travels in time. 



Wow that really looks like it. Thank you very much!

Not a problem, glad I could help!
